# Sliding bottom border of input fields not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a set of input fields and I would like to animate the border-bottom to slide in from left to right on focus using CSS animation only. I tried the following code but nothing happens. I am new with CSS animations.

**HTML**

Login

**CSS**

```
.fields
{
    color: #646c70;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 83%;
    position: relative;
}
.fields:after {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;  
  transform: scaleX(0);  
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.fields:focus:after { transform: scaleX(1); }
.fields:after{  transform-origin:  0% 50%; }
```

I am not sure what I did. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLogh7ak/1/)

Comment: You can't use the `:after` pseudo selector on an `input` field

Comment: @APAD, so what should I use?

Comment: Use a label with the input

Comment: A demo would be nice.

Comment: See https://codepen.io/SlouchyBeanie/pen/EOWMwL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can't use pseudo elements on single tag elements like `input`, you could wrap the `input` in a `label` and use a `span` as border ... and animate the `width` instead of `scale`.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 83%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fields {
  color: #646c70;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.fields + span {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.fields:focus + span {
  width: 110%;          /*  used calc first, but won't work on Edge  */
  -webkit-transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input class="fields" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
  <span></span>
</label>
```

Comment: I tried it in a fiddle but I can't see the sliding effect.

Comment: yes but I really can't see the line sliding from left to right. Instead on focus I see the border just light up.

Comment: @Ayan What browser do you use? ... For older one's you might need to add prefixed properties, for example some versions of Safari `-webkit-transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;`

Comment: Currently I am using Edge on mobile. I am gonna try it on Firefox tomorrow.

Comment: @Ayan Found the issue. Using both transition and calc() won't work on Edge. Updated my answer + here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hsLwzs61/3/